# std::getline and UTF16 (LE) filestream - not working

Tags: c++11, unicode

Well the following should work - I can't find a reason why it shouldn't:

```
    std::fstream f;
    std::string myoutput;
    f.imbue(std::locale(f.getloc(), new std::codecvt_utf16<wchar_t, std::little_endian | std::consume_header>));
    f.open("c:\\test.txt", std::ios::in);
    std::getline(f, myoutput);
```

The code is executed on the following file (in hex - it should spell "hello world"):

> FF FE 68 00 65 00 6C 00 6C 00 6F 00 20 00 77 00 6F 00 72 00 6C 00 64
>   00

The ultimate goal is to abstract the encoding away, always consider a file UTF-8 unless the first bytes are a BOM. Now above code would be executed after reading a BOM and noticing it is UTF-16. It should hence read UTF-16 file, and convert it to a utf-8 string.

However the std::getline does not ignore the BOM (easily fixed) but furthermore it does not respect the fact that UTF-16 uses 2 bytes. (And it stops after reading the first 3 bytes upon seeing "0" ).

Now of course I could use std::wfstream. But as I wish to "hide" the unicode type from the user for one thing all the "filestreams"  are stored inside a container for referencing. So the signature of all those filestreams has to be equal - and be based on `char` and `std::string`

Comment: `codecvt_utf16<wchar_t>` is designed for use with wide streams and `wstring` (a string of `wchar_t`s - that's what its template parameter indicates). What makes you believe this class is supposed to "convert to a utf-8 string"? There is no standard facility to convert to a UTF-8 encoded `std::string`. See a handy table at the bottom of [this article](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf16)

Comment: @n.m. Uh `std::codecvt_mode::consume_header`?? But anyways for now let's just consider I know a file is of X (UTF16/UTF32 code). However I wish to open it using basic_fstream<char>, and export it correctly as std::basic_string<char> - encoded as UTF8. Those are interface requirements set by other points I can't change. Now I wish to handle UTF16 & UTF32 completely transparent from the user (I can always manually read the BOM which I know will be in place if it isn't UTF-8).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you opened your file as `basic_fstream<char>`, you've already set both external and internal character width to 1 byte and the locale facet you're applying will never be used.

Either read into a string and apply [wstring_convert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert) twice, or apply wbuffer_convert to make the internal character width bigger, and then wstring_convert:

```
std::fstream f;
f.open("test.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);

std::wbuffer_convert<std::codecvt_utf16<wchar_t,
                           0x10ffff, // note your 2nd parameter was wrong
                           std::little_endian // or consume_header, not both
                     >> cvt1(f.rdbuf());
std::wistream wide_f(&cvt1);
std::wstring wstr;
std::getline(wide_f, wstr);

std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> cvt2;
std::string u8str = cvt2.to_bytes(wstr);

std::cout << u8str << '\n';
```

Comment: Is that "binary" flag here on purpose - to do the "trick"? - I guess it is to make the reading operation ignore special bytes?

Comment: @paul23 it's so that a read on Windows doesn't abort on `0x1A` -- not necessary given your input, but is necessary in general

Comment: Thanks, one final "question": can the same idea be used for writing to files? (So fstream<char>, input is utf-8 but I wish to save as UTF16/whatever.

Comment: @paul23 as always in C++ I/O, you would need wide char on the inside, char on the outside. You can mirror the use of wbuffer_convert from this answer to wrap an ofstream into a wostream

Comment: I'm sorry I have to ask this again.. But I can't seem to get this solution to work for UTF32 files (for the rest it's perfect it's just that I need that too). Using std::wbuffer_convert<std::codecvt_utf16<wchar_t (and the corresponding string types) doesn't work.. For example the bytes 0B D1 01 00  are interpretted as 2 characters - instead of a single (U+1D10B)